# Testing for prime number. Values not pushing into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I'm trying to push values into an array, then if the array holds just two values, declare it as a prime number. For some reason, the for loop doesn't seem to be sending any values into the array...

```
function primeOrNot() {
  var input = parseInt(prompt('Please, give me a number'));
  var list = [];
  list.push(1);
  list.push(input);
  for (var i = 2; i < input / 2; i++) {
    if (Math.floor(input / i) == input / i) {
      list.push(i);
    }
    if (list.length == 2) {
      alert('The number you chose is a prime number.');
    } else 'The number you chose is not a prime number. You lose.';
  }
  console.log(list);
}

primeOrNot();
```

Comment: There is also a chance my maths in the for loop isn't correct, I'm still trying to get my head around it!

Comment: change `== 2` to `>=2` to see what you have

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `}` in the `else`. This works:

```js
function primeOrNot() {
  var input = parseInt(prompt("Please, give me a number"));
  var list = [];
      list.push(1);
      list.push(input);
  for(var i=2; i<input/2; i++){
    if (Math.floor(input/i) == input/i) list.push(i);
  }
  if(list.length == 2){
   alert("The number you chose is a prime number.");
  } else alert("The number you chose is not a prime number. You   lose.")
  console.log(list);
}
primeOrNot();
```